# MySQL query to return 2 counts on same data field

Tags: mysql

I want to show 2 counts of the same data, one without a condition and with a condition, probably a very simple thing for most people on this list:

When I run this I get my Total of all machines:

```
SELECT COUNT(ComputerID) AS 'Grand Total'
FROM computers
```

When I run this I get the total of OnLine machines:

```
SELECT COUNT(ComputerID) AS 'OnLine Total'
FROM computers
WHERE LastContact > DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -6 MINUTE)
```

How can I combine the 2 into 1 query to show something like this:

```
Grand Total          OnLine Total
2,500                2,145
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'Grand Total',
       SUM(LastContact > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -6 MINUTE)) AS 'Online Total'
FROM computers
```

Comment: Hi Barmar, thanks for the input. That fails, there's an issue with SUM. Is SUM appropriate for what I want to display? I thought SUM was to add up all the results in the column? I just want to display the COUNT. Can SUM also do a COUNT in this situation?

Comment: `SUM()` can add up any expression. In this case, I'm adding the result  of `>`, which is 1 if the comparison is true, 0 when it's false.

Comment: Hi Barmar, if there's a favourite solution amongst the answers you guys gave me then you get the prize, for it's simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

Try selecting from two separate subqueries since you don't have to group by anything. E.g.:

```
    SELECT 
    (
        SELECT COUNT(ComputerID)
        FROM computers
    )  AS GrandTotal,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(ComputerID)
        FROM computers
        WHERE LastContact > DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -6 MINUTE)
    ) AS OnlineTotal
```

Oh, and one small piece of advice! It's helpful if you provide the table schema as well. In this case, your query is pretty simple, so I didn't need much more information. But if in the future you need help with a more complex query, consider outputting the schema to something like SQLFiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: You got it Matt, that displays exactly as I want, thanks! Thats  a valuable example for me too, as there are  a number queries I want to do a similar thing.

Comment: Nice! Here's another idea. If you need a more detailed breakdown of your data, e.g. counts of certain sets of conditions broken out by another field, like maybe ComputerBrand or ComputerOwner, you could accomplish this by using similar aliased subqueries and left joining them to a SELECT DISTINCT list of your categories. I do something similar when I build pivot tables for web reports, but to be fully dynamic it requires the use of a procedural language like PL/SQL for example. In my case I use ColdFusion with MySQL. You could accomplish the same with PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding Barmar's solution, it looks like there's just a missing comma after 'Grand Total' and before SUM(). It should work if you run:

```
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'Grand Total',
        SUM(LastContact > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -6 MINUTE)) AS 'Online Total'
    FROM computers
```

Remember that an expression evaluating as true returns the value 1, and false returns 0. What you are summing is every instance of the field for which that expression holds true (2,145 trues.)

Here's another solution implementing CASE WHEN - this is essentially the same logic as the above but you can have it return anything you want under each condition. This might help to clarify how Barmar's code works - it's saying the exact same thing, just in a different way. This approach would be useful if later on down the line you wanted to count certain values a different way (e.g. count certain computers as 2, or 3, or anything):

```
    SELECT COUNT(ComputerID) AS  'GrandTotal', 
        SUM(CASE WHEN LastContact > DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -6 MINUTE) 
            THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'OnlineTotal'
    FROM computers
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks Matt. You are correct and that now returns data exactly as I wanted, as does the CASE one. Regards Peter.

Comment: Cool. You should mark Barmar's answer as the correct one if that's what you are going with!

Comment: I like my solution because it's more concise. The CASE version has one feature, though: it's standard SQL, so it should work with other databases.